# Why am I getting, "URI formats are not supported" with this code?

Tags: c#, reflection, uri, filestream

I have this code that should assign a string path value to the "uripath" string variable:

```
private readonly FileStream _fileStream;

. . .

string uriPath = GetExecutionFolder() + "\\AppLogMsgs.txt";
_fileStream = File.OpenWrite(uriPath); 

. . .

private string GetExecutionFolder()
{
    return Path.GetDirectoryName       
(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
}
```

...but it crashes when trying to execute the "*_fileStream = File.OpenWrite(uriPath);*" line.

Why, and what do I need to do to rectify this revoltin' development?

The value of "uriPath" when it crashes is:

**file:\C:\Projects\ReportScheduler\ReportScheduler\bin\Debug\AppLogMsgs.txt**

Comment: Can you add what is the actual value of uriPath at the exception time?

Comment: I think you need just _System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your intent is to know the location ***of the loaded file that contains the manifest*** then you could change your method to

```
private string GetExecutionFolder()
{
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
}
```

[See Location Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`AssemblyName.CodeBase` property returns the location of the assembly as a URL and as the assembly is a local file the string begins with **file:\**

Just need to remove this part from `uriPath` and should work as expected:

```
string uriPath = GetExecutionFolder() + "\\AppLogMsgs.txt";
uriPath = uriPath.Replace("file:\\", string.Empty);
_fileStream = File.OpenWrite(uriPath);
```